# output string name of the class with the namespace

Tags: php, pdo

```
namespace modules\quiz\model\quiz\valueObjects;

class QuizVO {

 }
```

Is there a programatic way to retrieve string name of the class along with the package name.

for instance (Please note, the class that is using the QuizVO is in a different namespace)

```
use modules\quiz\model\quiz\valueObjects\QuizVO;

$statement->setFetchMode(\PDO::FETCH_CLASS, QuizVO::class); //need class with package name here
```

instead of

```
$statement->setFetchMode(\PDO::FETCH_CLASS, 'modules\quiz\model\quiz\valueObjects\QuizVO');
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is [possibly as of PHP 5.5](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/class_name_scalars) in exactly the same way as you proposed it:

```
ClassName::class
```

---

Before PHP 5.5 you'll need to create an object of your wanted class and use [`get_class`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.get-class.php)

Comment: ah... that's why it's creating problem, any solution for earlier versions?

Comment: @user2727195 I amended my answer.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, just tried this and it works, what do you think about this. $statement->setFetchMode(\PDO::FETCH_CLASS, get_class(new QuizVO()));

Comment: @user2727195 Well, that's certainly easier…

Answer (score 0):

```
$statement->setFetchMode(\PDO::FETCH_CLASS, get_class(new QuizVO()));
```